# Bootstrap 4 (v4.1.1) date time picker drop down issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Can somebody fix this issue for bootstrap latest version (v4.1.1). Dropdown is not showing correctly. or suggest me a good date time picker for bootstrap latest version.

**[Please check Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/sinjuangajan/pen/OEVBBR)**

```
 <section class="jumbotron text-center ">
    <form>
        <div class="form-row justify-content-md-center">

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Bootstrap 4 (v4.1.1 ) Date Time Picker</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suggested time for visit*" aria-label="Suggested time for visit*" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="datetimepicker1">
                    <div class="input-group-append input-group-addon">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

I've used this datepicker with the last version of Bootstrap :

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've added this at the end of the JavaScript code :

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
});
```

Here is the Jsfiddle, it did work : https://jsfiddle.net/jrafo826/
Just changed the style a little bit ! You need to add glyphicon yourself though.